# centos 6.5 postfix postgresql support

Tags: postfix, centos6

i m trying to use postfix with postgres to create a virtual users mail boxes. 
I get the following errors :

```
fatal: unsupported dictionary type: pgsql 
warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd pid 22827 exit status 1
warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
```

is there any additional repos that provides postfix with postgres support?

thanks

Comment: have you checked epel? I don't know off the top of my head but that is where i would START.

Comment: Basically it looks like Redhat removed the support from the RPM, although if you recompile the package with this line in your .rpmmacros `%PGSQL 1` you'll have the support.  Ref: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.mail.postfix.user/227287

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Centos 7. I needed to recompile Postfix with appropriate flags, there's how to do that: http://blog.solusipse.net/posts/compiling-postfix-with-postgresql-support-on-centos-7/

Step by step

- Download and extract postfix

  ```
  wget ftp://ftp.its.cz/MIRRORS/ftp.porcupine.org/mirrors/postfix-release/official/postfix-2.11.3.tar.gz && tar xvf postfix-2.11.3.tar.gz
  ```
- Prepare script.

> echo "make makefiles CCARGS='-DHAS_PGSQL -I/usr/local/include/pgsql -fPIC -DUSE_TLS -DUSE_SSL -DUSE_SASL_AUTH -DUSE_CYRUS_SASL -DPREFIX=\"/usr\" -DHAS_LDAP -DLDAP_DEPRECATED=1 -DHAS_PCRE -I/usr/include/openssl -I/usr/include/sasl  -I/usr/include' AUXLIBS='-L/usr/local/lib -lpq -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib64/openssl -lssl -lcrypto -L/usr/lib64/sasl2 -lsasl2 -lpcre -lz -lm -lldap -llber -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib64/openssl -pie -Wl,-z,relro' OPT='-O' DEBUG='-g'" > build-postfix.sh && chmod a+x build-postfix.sh

- Install all dependencies, but first you need to enable CentOS Plus repository.

  ```
  yum install libdb libdb-devel gcc openssl openssl-devel pcre pcre-devel openldap-devel cyrus-sasl cyrus-sasl-devel openldap postgresql postgresql-devel
  ```
- Execute it

  ```
  ./build-postfix.sh
  ```